# Algorithm to determine best image saving format

Tags: c#, performance, image, algorithm, math

I've got an image that could be a photograph or a screenshot. I want to make sure that the images get saved in an appropriate format. I am talking about jpeg and png at this point.

How can I determine if it would be better to save an image as .jpeg because it is/contains a photo? Also, if the image contains a **used** alpha channel, png is obviously appropriated.

The simplest way would be to save the image two times with different image formats into a memory stream and compare the corresponding data size. Obviously, this is very resource intensive and - in my opinion - not the way to go.

Anybody got suggestions?

Comment: Where does this image come from? In what format is it stored, i.e. what's the input type for the method that you are trying to write?

Comment: Neither a photograph or a screenshot will contain Alpha.

Comment: @Mark the screenshots I am talking about can contain alpha.

Comment: What if it's a screenshot of an image viewer containing a photograph?

Comment: @MarkRansom And it would be appropriate to store an alpha channel with DCT as well [transparent film masks...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look for occurances of continuous runs of the same color, as these are very uncommon in photographs.  Of course, with modern UIs, gradient effects are making these less common in screenshots.  It's still fairly typical to have solid color areas (grays or whites, in particular), so it's a reasonable heuristic, if you want something quick.  You might want to exclude max-intensity white or min-intensity black, as over-exposed or under-exposed photographs can contain large patches of these colors.

Comment: Is there a commonly used algorithm to analyze an image that way?

Comment: @nikeee13, I'm not familiar with a standard algorithm for this, but it's probably sufficient to sample along the rows and count consecutive identical pixels.  If you ever get over a threshold count, flag it as non-photo.  You can get fancier with your measurements and perhaps compute some statistics, but even just finding five pixels in a row is a pretty good indicator it's not a photo (even ignoring lighting gradients on the surfaces being photographed, CCD noise will typically cause dither at least on the order of 1 brightness unit.)